# Function to return Unicode Value

Tags: microsoft-excel

If a cell, say cell **A1,** contains ASCII text:

**A**

then I can use the *CODE()* function to return its numerical equivalent.  That is:

=CODE(A1)  will display **65**

Is there a function similar to *CODE()* that will return the numerical equivalent if **A1** contains a Unicode character??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [UNICODE function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/unicode-function-HA102753274.aspx) and the [UNICHAR function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/UNICHAR-function-ffeb64f5-f131-44c6-b332-5cd72f0659b8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) were introduced to Excel with Office 2013.

You would need a VBA *User Defined Function* or UDF for previous versions.